# Dell XT2 Upgrade to Windows 8, Embedded WWAN Not Turned On

Tags: windows-8, dell-inspiron, embedded, mobile-broadband, wwan

I've been working on a friend's computer, and upgraded her Tablet/Laptop Inspiron XT2 (originally with XP Media) to Windows 8 Pro. The laptop has an embedded (believe it's the 5600) WAN card for Verizon. I got the driver installed from Dell's website, yet Verizon's Broadband software (VZAccess) tells me it's not turned on. I've checked hardware switches, the fn+f4 (or whichever combo it was), looked in network connections, checked using Unknown Devices to detect, and still no avail. I have two devices in device manager, one is unknown and the other is 5880 (fingerprint scanner), but so far no WWAN card.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Can you obtain a [device ID](http://superuser.com/a/265330/138343) for the unknown device?

Comment: Yea, I have to wait till I can get remoted into her computer.

Comment: Okay, Device ID is USB\VID_1B96&PID_0001&REV_0000&MI_02 - &MI_02 --- Still stumped on this.

Comment: That unknown device seems to be an N-Trig DuoSense Digitizer (see [1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprohardware/thread/af4f7a9d-f1c9-44ce-97c9-28e3d1a442a5), [2](http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=4007), [3](http://www.systemcenter.nu/index.php/2009/10/27/dell-latitude-xt2-unknown-devices-in-windows-7/), [4](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Windows-7-Beta-and-Test-Reply-Only/can-you-identify-this-unknown-hardware-device-by-its/td-p/118369)). Check the BIOS to see whether the device is disabled. Otherwise if it's not even detected, could be a hardware issue.

Comment: Hmm, well the two unknown devices aren't what I'm worried about, as my friend never uses the touchscreen. The wwan card not being found is definitely a problem. At least on the VZW application side. Any ideas on getting it to detect via VZW's connection manager? Ideally it worked before the upgrade (from ugh, XP).

Comment: similar issue no answer